# How to remove data from a MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net, memorystream

I cannot get this to work. I have a MemoryStream object. This class
has a Position property that tells you how many bytes you have read.

What I want to do is to delete all the bytes between 0 and Position-1

I tried this:

```
MemoryStream ms = ...
ms.SetLength(ms.Length - ms.Position);
```

but at some point my data gets corrupted.

So I ended up doing this

```
MemoryStream ms = ...
byte[] rest = new byte[ms.Length - ms.Position];
ms.Read(rest, 0, (int)(ms.Length - ms.Position));
ms.Dispose();
ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(rest, 0, rest.Length);
```

which works but is not really efficient.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't delete data from a `MemoryStream` - the cleanest would be to create a new memory stream based on the data you want:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(someData);
//ms.Position changes here
//...
byte[] data = ms.ToArray().Skip((int)ms.Position).ToArray();
ms = new MemoryStream(data);
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? So what SetLength does? Thanks

Comment: @Moonlit - you can *truncate* the data, but not delete arbitrary blocks, you need to copy data one way or the other. Having said that my code is not any better than yours (other than you are relying on `ms.Read()` to copy all bytes)

Answer (score 17):

This should work and be much more efficient than creating a new buffer:

```
byte[] buf = ms.GetBuffer();            
Buffer.BlockCopy(buf, numberOfBytesToRemove, buf, 0, (int)ms.Length - numberOfBytesToRemove);
ms.SetLength(ms.Length - numberOfBytesToRemove);
```

MemoryStream.GetBuffer() gives you access to the existing buffer, so you can move bytes around without creating a new buffer.

Of course you'll need to be careful about out-of-bounds issues.

Answer (score 6):

Calling `ms.SetLength(ms.Length - ms.Position)` won't remove the bytes between `0` and `ms.Position-1`, in fact it will remove bytes between `ms.Length - ms.Position` and `ms.Length`.

Why not just write:

```
byte[] rest;
ms.Write(rest, ms.Length-ms.Position, rest.Length);
```

Comment: Thanks about the explanation for the SetLength method

Answer (score 0):

```
 var _ = new MemoryStream();
 _.Write(buf.GetBuffer(), (int)buf.Position, (int)buf.Length - (int)buf.Position);
 buf = _;
```