# Reading part of a file into a Stream in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have some files which are 'offsetted' Zip files in that they have 4 extra bytes at the begining which must be ignored when extracting them.

I've been using ReadAllBytes/WriteAllBytes (with an offset of 4) - that works but obviously I have to write read/write/read the file which is slow.

I'd prefer to use System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive to read from a Stream loaded from the file (sans the first 4 bytes) - but I cannot figure-out the steps required to do that?

I tried 'Seek' but ZipArchive ignores position 
I cannot seem to get Byte Arrays to pass into System.IO.Compression at all...

Ideas?

Comment: When you say "read/write/read the file" are you writing it back to the filesystem? Or simply messing with the read data in the stream?

Comment: This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5733696/3485669) has a few solutions including new MemoryStream creation and direct buffer manipulation - hopefully it will get you closer to your desired solution?

Comment: Seems I fluked the right answer after only about 200 variations - that article helped a bit but I struggle between C# and Powershell - Powershell seems to struggle with typing/parameters when calling Net?

Answer (score 2):

Finally!

After trying all manner of hoop-jumping, it seems the simplest answer was the right one

```
$bytes = [system.io.file]::ReadAllBytes("file.zip4")
$ms = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream -Argumentlist $bytes,4,($bytes.length-4)
$arch = New-Object System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive($ms)
```

I can then process $arch.Entries and extract things just fine - reading the file once and processing it instead of reading it, writing 'most' of it back to disc, reading that file back again!!

Comment: Nice - dare I ask what, in nature, produces the 4-byte offset Zip archive?

Comment: I believe they're addons for a Train Simulator (RWP files) - I'm just harnessing my 'silent installer' skills for someone and this is one of their "installers"

The clue came when 7Zip opened them AOK (Trid, SignSrch and Offzip having failed to ID them) - 7Zip describes them as a '4 byte offset Zip" so they're likely used outside of just this context, tho I've not seen anything like this

I suspect 7Zip will open ANY zip-header content in any file perhaps?