# Lazily transform data in C# Stream

Tags: c#

I read from a stream that contains CRLF each X bytes (for me X is 2033 because the file is generated with [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16), I put X to 4 in sample code). I would like to transform the stream into another stream without this CRLF. The new stream will be deserialized as xml.

Likewise, I can do it easily and runs gracefully in this way:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class CREliminator
{
    public const int BcpChunkSize = 4;
    public Stream Run(StreamReader reader)
    {
        var auxstream = new MemoryStream();
        var auxwriter = new StreamWriter(auxstream);
        var chunk = new char[BcpChunkSize];
        do
        {
            var n_bytes =
                reader
               .ReadBlock(chunk, 0, BcpChunkSize);

            auxwriter.Write(chunk[..n_bytes]);
            auxwriter.Flush();

            if (n_bytes == BcpChunkSize)
            {
                char[] chunk2 = new char[2];
                n_bytes = reader.ReadBlock(chunk2, 0, 2);
            }

        } while (!reader.EndOfStream);
        auxstream.Position = 0;
        return auxstream;
    }
}

public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var CRLF="\r\n";
        var string_data = $"<doc{CRLF}umen{CRLF}t>A<{CRLF}/doc{CRLF}umen{CRLF}t>";
        var expected = string_data.Replace(CRLF, "");
        // to stream
        var memory = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string_data));
        var data = new StreamReader(memory);
        // act
        var result = new CREliminator().Run(data);
        // assert
        var x = XDocument.Load(result);
        Assert.Equal(expected, x.ToString());
    }
}
```

But this code **loads all stream in memory** before to return the new stream.

My question is, how can do it in a Lazy mode? I mean, processing stream when some process is reading from new stream.

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps you should implement `StreamReader` and transform as the the `Read` calls happen

Comment: @DanielA.White , yes, I guess this is the way, but I see more other methods to override. The new stream is sent to a [Xml Deserializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0) and I don't know how it works internally.

Comment: I would read file with streamreader one character at a time and write all character except CRLF using a streamwriter.

Comment: why do you return a StreamReader? I'd return a simple Stream, instead. Consumer has the responsibility to instance and use a reader.

Comment: @MarioVernari, god point, I can return just a stream. Can this help with issue?

Comment: @daniherrera well, if you return the stream (i.e. auxstream), the outside consumer can read while your function (i.e. the producer) scans the input. However, I'd pass a Stream as input as well. Same reason as before.

Comment: @MarioVernari, I updated the Q changing StreamReader with a Stream. In question, they are a simple test that stream should pass. Thanks about your comments.

Comment: Your main problem is that you're using a `MemoryStream`. As the name implies, this stream is stored in memory. Therefore copying the entire stream that `reader` is reading to a `MemoryStream` stores the entire thing in memory. Try bypassing the `MemoryStream` entirely by passing the data directly if possible, or use a [stream that supports simultaneous reading and writing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12328307/10601203) so you can process the data as it's getting added to the stream so you don't have to wait for the whole thing to be loaded into memory.

Comment: @Jesse, your linked sample also uses a `MemortStream`as inner stream, but I understand what are you explaining. I was so lazy to implement all abstract `Stream` methods but I see that this is the way.

Comment: Yes the example I posted does use a `MemoryStream`. You may be able to use that in combination with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16487602/10601203) in order to remove data from the stream as it's read. Not quite sure how performance efficient it is though.

Comment: @daniherrera i deleted my answer because it was an idea, but i haven't time to try it. Sorry!

Comment: @daniherrera I'm sure I'm missing something, but you do need all data in memory in order to deserialize it into xml. By using both StreamReader and StreamWriter I think you're actually doubling the memory you're using. Since you cannot avoid loading the whole file, can't you just read bytes first and work with them? Or you could use a `FileStream` and remove bytes from each block you read

Comment: thanks @Phate01, good point.

Comment: @MarioVernari , is ok, thanks about your answer, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `Stream.Read` method needs to be implemented:

- Read from source stream in chunks
- Skip 2 bytes after every chunk

```cs
using System.Buffers;
using System.Text;

var sourceString = string.Concat(
    Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(_ => "Foo \r\nBar \r\nBaz!\r\n"));
Console.WriteLine("Source: " + sourceString);

var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false);
var sourceBytes = encoding.GetBytes(sourceString);

using var stream = new MemoryStream(sourceBytes);
using var filter = new CrLfFilteringStream(stream, 4);
using var reader = new StreamReader(filter, encoding);

var res = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine("Result: " + res);

public class CrLfFilteringStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream _stream;
    private readonly int _chunkSize;
    private readonly byte[] _chunk;
    private int _chunkPosition;
    private int _chunkLength;

    public CrLfFilteringStream(Stream stream, int chunkSize)
    {
        _stream = stream ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));
        _chunkSize = chunkSize;
        _chunkPosition = chunkSize;
        _chunkLength = chunkSize;
        _chunk = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(chunkSize);
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var toRead = count;
        var bufferPosition = 0;
        Span<byte> sink = stackalloc byte[2];

        while (toRead > 0 && _chunkLength > 0)
        {
            if (_chunkPosition >= _chunkSize)
            {
                _chunkPosition = 0;
                _chunkLength = _stream.Read(_chunk, 0, _chunkSize);

                // Skip CR LF.
                _stream.Read(sink);
            }

            var currentRead = Math.Min(_chunkLength, toRead);
            Array.Copy(_chunk, _chunkPosition, buffer, bufferPosition, currentRead);
            toRead -= currentRead;
            bufferPosition += currentRead;
            _chunkPosition += currentRead;
        }

        return count - toRead;
    }

    public override void Flush() => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override void SetLength(long value) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanSeek => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override long Length => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override long Position
    {
        get => throw new NotSupportedException();
        set => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(_chunk);

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

This code rents a single chunk-sized buffer from `ArrayPool` and does not allocate anything else (besides `CrLfFilteringStream` instance).